# How to mock value the hybrid property of sqlalchemy model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mocking, pytest, patch

I have a table:

```
class A(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    age = Column(Integer)

    @hybrid_property
    def is_adult(self):
        if self.age > 18:
            return True
        return False
```

Usage of the table:

```
def check_adult():
    this_user = A.query.first()
    is_adult = this_user.is_adult
    if this_user.is_adult:
        return "Yes"
    else:
        return "No"
```

Now to write unit test for this chunk of code, I am unable to find the way to mock the is_adult value.

```
@patch("A")
def test_check_adult(mock_A):
    this_user = mock_A.return_value.query.return_value.first.return_value
    this_user.is_adult = True
    assert check_adult() == "Yes"
```

Please provide the way to mock the hybrid_property and hybrid_method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mock_A.return_value` would mock `A()`, but you are not calling `A`, but accessing its attribute `A.query` etc., so

```
this_user = mock_A.query.first.return_value
```

---

As an aside, using a boolean expression in an if-statement and returning `True` or `False` is a bit redundant. Just use the boolean expression itself:

```
class A(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    age = Column(Integer)

    @hybrid_property
    def is_adult(self):
        return self.age > 18
```

That has the added benefit of working directly in query context as well, so you do not need to specify `@is_adult.expression` separately.

Comment: Not working! Still unable to mock value `this_user.is_adult`. `ValueError: not enough values to unpack` occured!

Comment: Without a proper traceback it is hard to say this or that, but that sounds far removed from the issue at hand. No unpacking takes place anywhere in the code example you have presented in the question.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, it worked. The error was caused due to different issue.